# Magic Mouse on Windows Vista machine

Tags: windows, mouse, scrolling, magic-mouse

i just got a magic mouse for my vista basic dell laptop.

i installed the 32bit driver for it by following [uneasysilence instruction](http://uneasysilence.com/archive/2009/11/14588/).
i have basic functions like left and right click.

i read some comments on uneasysilence. it appears that some people manage to get at least vertical scrolling working in some app like firefox.

however, i cannot get scrolling to work, vertical or horizontal. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: well i installed it on a windows 7 machine and it works. strange.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure those gestures are actually supported by Windows?

The article only tells us you can get it working under Windows so that it's not a complete waste of money. Sadly, everybody seems to be quoting this article (or Gizmodo quoting it), so it's hard to tell whether anyone else has actually tried it.

Plus my guess would be that it's more aimed for Bootcamp users than native Windows users...

Quotes from Apple:

> When using an Apple Magic Mouse with
>   Microsoft Windows XP or Vista,
>   vertical scrolling and two-finger
>   swiping may not work.
>
> If you are using Mac OS X v10.6 Snow
>   Leopard, vertical scrolling in Windows
>   using a Magic Mouse is currently
>   supported only on iMac (Late 2009)
>   computers. Swiping is not supported.

Comment: i read some comments on uneasysilence. it appears that some people manage to get at least vertical scrolling working in some app like firefox.