# Can I use my Apple magic mouse and Apple wireless keyboard with my Windows Vista machine?

Tags: macos, windows-vista, magic-mouse, wireless-keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magic Mouse on Windows Vista machine](https://superuser.com/questions/86593/magic-mouse-on-windows-vista-machine)

Is it possible to:

A)  Use these 2 devices with my Windows Vista machine
B)  Be able to switch them between my Windows machine and my Mac?

Comment: Related: [Magic Mouse on Windows Vista machine](http://superuser.com/questions/86593/magic-mouse-on-windows-vista-machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's USB, it will work on both machines. You can't switch from one to the other but they will work both at the sime time on the same computer. You can then disconnect them and put them back on the Mac or Vista and it's gonna work.

Comment: As I said the Apple Magic mouse and Apple Wireless Keyboard i.e. both are wireless.

Comment: So it's Bluetooth I assume? Why downvote?

Comment: @r0ca They are bluetooth, so if the Vista computer has bluetooth device, they should work, but they will have reduced functionality until drivers are installed.

Comment: If it's bluetooth, you need to have it on both computers, then, configure it, Vista don't care about apple stuff

Comment: @AndrejaKo Yes i know... And I'm pretty sure even if drivers are loaded on Vista it will not have the full functionality but at least it will work! As his question of course!

Comment: So I just have to buy a blue tooth USB stick or wha?