# bluetooth doesn't recognize mouse (and other devices)... sometimes

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, mouse, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magic Mouse on Windows Vista machine](https://superuser.com/questions/86593/magic-mouse-on-windows-vista-machine)

I have a problem with bluetooth with Vista, running on my MacBook. It often doesn't recognize my wireless Magic Mouse. And I saw that it even doesn't seem to start as the pictogram in the task-bar isn't there most of the time I run Vista. But I'm only an Apple-nerd, so I don't know to much about this issue on Vista. When reinstalling Boothcamp or other updates, then once in a while bluetooth recognizes my own mouse (and other devices from some neighbours... so that implicates that the problem must be the bluetooth function in the first place, not my mouse.) Is there some update for the bluetooth application?

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

I've had many issues with Windows Vista and bluetooth mice. Some times the mouse wouldn't be recognized and I had to re-scan it with the bluetooth application. I suggest either you reinstall the mouse driver or use an alternative Bluetooth software like [BlueSoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/)

Comment: reinstalling helps for just some times, bluesoleil could be an option, but paying without knowing that it definitely helps... doesn't make me happy right know. But thanks for your advice.

Comment: If it's possible you should change your operating system for Windows 7, I've had less bluetooth issues after having migrated.